# Getting minecraft client's coordinates in python

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is a bit more of an experimental project. I am trying to get a Minecraft player's XYZ coordinates in Python. Whether it be through reading memory locations or reading log files, does anyone have any ideas as to how this could be achieved?

Comment: In real-time or after saving the world?

Comment: In real time. I.e. I have a loop in python which repetitively checks for the player's location.

Comment: I think this would be best on StackOverflow

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better suited for StackOverflow rather than here. We're not the best place to ask for coding help.

Comment: [There's this, but it's for pi edition](https://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2013/02/raspberry-pi-minecraft-auto-bridge.html). If you can forge (java), then you can [this](https://skmedix.github.io/ForgeJavaDocs/javadoc/forge/1.9.4-12.17.0.2051/net/minecraft/entity/player/EntityPlayer.html)

Comment: I suggest you look into writing mods/plugins (in Java, not in Python). Because it's Java, there aren't stable memory addresses. Java also has some sort of debugger API, so you coudl research that, but it'll be much more complicated.